# How to understand the linear relation between Fermi level $E_F$ and the length $L$ of the slab in Hall effect and spin Hall effect?

Tags: chemical-potential, hall-effect

I am following [this paper](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.83.1834) to learn the physics of the spin Hall effect. Unlike the conventional Hall effect, the role of the external magnetic field $\vec{B}$ has been replaced by the effective magnetic field $\vec{m}$ due to the spin-orbit coupling effect, as shown in the left column of the following figure:

[image]

What confuses me is the right column of the exhibited figure. Namely, how to understand the linear relation between Fermi level $E_F$ and the length $L$ of the slab in Hall effect and spin Hall effect?